# Way to convert progression of number to two character string

Tags: php, string, type-conversion

Is there any way convert a limited progression of number (integer) in a two characters string?

```
from:
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ..., 300]

to:
[aa, ab, ac, ad, ae, af, ag, ..., xb]
```

My first try:

```
$counter = 'a';
foreach ($imgs as $key => $img) {
  $counter ++;
  var_dump($key.' '.$counter);
}
```

Second try:

```
$chrs = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z'];
foreach ($imgs as $key => $img) {
  $idx = $n % $chrs_length;
  $chr = $chrs[$idx];
  var_dump($key.' '.$chrs[$idx].);
}
```

Comment: You can convert even a single integer into a two-character string. Have you [**tried anything**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) so far?

Comment: @ObsidianAge well actually it's one week I'm looking for a solution also more widely on Google. Anyway thanks

Comment: @AngusSimons your statement of 1 week doesn't make any sense.  And you could translate it using the `chr` function, but I'm not sure where AA and XB originated from.

Comment: @Forbs `chr` output all the ascii not only letters

Comment: Yes and and you would have to code around, Don't Panic's answer works I forgot that Z++ is AA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not clear if there needs to be any direct relationship between the specific numbers and the two character codes. If you just need the same number of codes as you have numbers, you can do it like this:

```
$code = 'aa';
foreach ($integers as $int) {
    $codes[] = $code++;
}
```

Comment: Seriously...thanks. I was trying starting from `$code = 'a'` instead of `aa`. Thanks a lot